# Typo3 backend css keeps disappearing?

Tags: css, backend, typo3

I have a typo3 system which works mostly fine, however when ever I install a new extension the CSS on the back-end goes away, or seems to be parsed only partially.

screen shot at : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BacTY.png

I've tried several different extension and they all seem to do this.

Typo3 version 4.4.6

If anyone has any ideas... all help is valued and appreciated. Ta!

Comment: How are the .css files referenced in backend? Are they accessible and show the CSS rules, when you open them directly?

Comment: In general, I suggest to contact the official typo3 mailing lists (http://lists.typo3.org), where you receive better support than here.

Comment: Has this been resolved? Please check and mark one answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you have installed the system extension "t3skin". It brings the default skin and is shipped with TYPO3.

If it is installed, check whether your .htaccess has the gzip rules enabled, in case of you have $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['compressionLevel'] set.

Comment: I just checked the .htaccess file - there's nothing set to enable gzip compression. But also in the conf file there's no "$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['compressionLevel'] " var set either

Comment: And is t3skin installed? You can check that also in typo3conf/localconf.php, option $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXT']['extList']

Comment: ... and do you have any other skin extension installed?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have some trouble with gzip compressed css here. Newer versions of TYPO3 added  this feature to speed things up. Typically TYPO3 can't write to your .htaccess file which is why you have to do it manually. Just add the following lines to your .htaccess file:

```
 <FilesMatch "\.js\.gzip$">
 AddType "text/javascript" .gzip
 </FilesMatch>
 <FilesMatch "\.css\.gzip$">
  AddType "text/css" .gzip
  </FilesMatch>
  AddEncoding gzip .gzip
```

Note that the .htaccess file is hidden and some ftp / sftp clients won't find it with their default settings. That's basically what StephenKing says just a lil more elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in localconf.php:

`$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['compressionLevel'] = '0'`

It helped in my installation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had `mod_deflate` installed and good `.htaccess`, but in vhost configuration `.htaccess` reading was disabled by `AllowOverride None`, so I turned `AllowOverride` in `All` and all worked.

```
AllowOverride All
```

Restart Apache :

```
apache2ctl restart
```