# CSS keeps disappearing with enabled BE compression Typo3 4.5.5+ and with any Windows browser?

Tags: windows, firefox, google-chrome, opera, typo3

In my TYPO3 4.5.5, 4.6.8, 4.7.0 installation I've enabled the BE compression and I've added the filetype css.gzip and js.gzip to the gzip encoding however it seems to work only when I use Linux to load the backend. When I load the backend from a Windows box the backend css keeps disappearing like in this question: [Typo3 backend css keeps disappearing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068286/typo3-backend-css-keeps-disappearing). I've lighttpd and xdebug installed. How can I trace this problem? What can I do better? When I load the BE either the css is gone and I see a white background and all the links or the css is gone and I see nothing but a grey background? This happens to me with Opera, Firefox, Chrome and IE but only in Windows. It works good in my vmware Linux with Opera.

Here is the head of the html document I receive in Windows:

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../typo3temp/compressor/ext-all-notheme-448c172dae3b05a28e37e929acd3dfbd.css.gzip?1338165817" media="all">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../typo3temp/compressor/xtheme-t3skin-b1eb282b32815f23ab802d5f31be8d32.css.gzip?1338165817" media="all">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../typo3temp/compressor/merged-13c77c78c44baff349c74df3ad74c358-2f57f69c13098471b93b4fa184d2bf2c.css.gzip?1338198129" media="all">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../typo3temp/compressor/opendocs-452c8b724f6c5a4422f90810531ca5a5.css.gzip?1338166068" media="all">  

     <script src="../typo3temp/compressor/prototype-8eb6a2a9407e9463f08359cc9bad4c87.js.gzip" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../typo3temp/compressor/effects-7755a9120837eb7b8dff7c8dd2348199.js.gzip" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../typo3temp/compressor/builder-4fb5884be8295df97135419557d212dd.js.gzip" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../typo3temp/compressor/effects-7755a9120837eb7b8dff7c8dd2348199.js.gzip" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../typo3temp/compressor/dragdrop-57bf1a5e32454608dbccbef2d2662a48.js.gzip" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../typo3temp/compressor/controls-722f428342d0f41d9510f8acd197ea7f.js.gzip" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../typo3temp/compressor/scriptaculous-8f7107540a1c9b395c16bfcafedf2cd2.js.gzip" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../typo3temp/compressor/ext-base-c203c25c05d8ccea2297e64c157fc2be.js.gzip" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../typo3temp/compressor/ext-all-97d26ae0274f2fc5953506492a4c41d4.js.gzip" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../typo3temp/compressor/ext-lang-de-6eab6fa8f67816fcbfac59dc46c48f64.js.gzip" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Here is my lighttpd rules:

```
 $HTTP["url"] =~ "\.js\.gzip$" {
    setenv.add-response-header = ("Content-Encoding" => "x-gzip")
    mimetype.assign = ( "js.gzip" => ".gzip" )
 }

 $HTTP["url"] =~ "\.css\.gzip$" {
      setenv.add-response-header = ("Content-Encoding" => "x-gzip")
      mimetype.assign = ( "css.gzip" => ".gzip" )
 }

 compress.allowed-encodings = ( "gzip", "deflate")
 compress.cache-dir = "/tmp/lighttpdcompress/"
 compress.filetype  = ( "text/html", "text/plain", "text/css", "text/xml", 
 "application/x-javascript" )
```

This is my response header from backend.php:

```
 Cache-Control  max-age=1728000, no-cache, must-revalidate
 Connection         close
 Content-Encoding   gzip
 Content-Type   text/html;charset=utf-8
 Date   Wed, 30 May 2012 12:17:50 GMT
 Expires    Tue, 19 Jun 2012 12:17:49 GMT, 0
 Last-Modified  Wed, 30 May 2012 12:17:49 GMT
 Pragma no-cache
 Server lighttpd/1.4.29
 Transfer-Encoding  chunked
 Vary   Accept-Encoding
 X-Powered-By   PHP/5.3.8
```

Here is my request header:

```
 Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
 Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate
 Accept-Language    en-us,en;q=0.5
 Connection keep-alive
 Host   XXXX
 Referer    XXXX
 User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
```

This is my post from the login screen:

```
 challenge  XXXXXX
 commandLI  Login
 interface  backend
 loginRefresh   
 login_status   login
 p_field    
 redirect_url   backend.php
 userident  XXXXX
 username   XXXXX
```

After loading I can see only an empty grey screen but with firebug I can see that all the source code and the css files is loaded into my browser? My backend really works only in Linux and Opera (maybe Firefox)???

Edit: I've checked a virtual machine with Firefox 12 and Windows 7 Ultimate and it's working???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your HTTP Headers. Are they correct? Probably your .htaccess rules does not work correct.

You can track the headers with the [Firefox Plugin Live HTTP Headers](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/). Or you can use an proxy like [webscarab](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebScarab_Project) to track the HTTP.

Comment: But why does it works in Opera and Linux? I can check the headers but I don't know how it can solve the problem? Do you have an example of a skrewed header? I don't use Apache so no .htaccess.

Comment: If the content is send via gzip, you need to have a line "Content-Encoding: gzip" in your header. If you use firefox firebug, can you see your css-files, or are they gziped?

Comment: I've checked a virtual machine with Firefox 12 and Windows 7 Ultimate and it's working???

Comment: check "Content-Encoding   gzip" for your CSS/JS Files! And perhaps test setenv.add-response-header = ("Content-Encoding" => "gzip") (gzip instead of x-gzip)

Comment: Changing Content-Encoding from x-gzip to gzip seems to solve it partially. It still doesn't work in IE and Opera 12? But seems to work in Firefox 12 and Opera 11. Really strange issue?

Comment: perhaps caching? do not know.

Comment: Windows 7 and Chrome doesn't work either. This is with the newest Typo3 4.7.0?